# Want to set selenium to click a target until a certain element is visible

Tags: selenium, click, element, visible

I'm trying to make an automated checkout for a website and I want it to click the add to cart button until the checkout button is visible but there is only the option to click the button once and wait until the checkout button is visible.

Comment: depends on your implementation and when the button shows up, can you provide more details?

Comment: idk what you asked the first part but the button (checkout button) shows up when the item has been added to cart. im using regular selenium ide if that helps

Comment: So you want to keep clicking the button until checkout shows?

Comment: yes. i have it set to selenium ide so i can change the format to python or java or whatever's easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing it on Eclipse, this might help.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 500);
WebElement selectElement = 
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                   .visibilityOfElementLocated(
                        By.id("writeherethenameofbutton")));


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='GET THE CORRECT XPATH']")).click();
```

I hope this helps!!

Comment: I believe this does not anwser the question.